# CORS Preflight response includes Vary:Origin and Access-Control-Max-Age?

Tags: cors, cross-domain, browser-cache, preflight

I would like to know how browsers handle CORS Preflight response that includes both **Vary: Origin** and **Access-Control-Max-Age** headers.

This statement is from https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

> Resources that wish to enable themselves to be shared with multiple
>   Origins but do not respond uniformly with "*" must in practice
>   generate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header dynamically in
>   response to every request they wish to allow. As a consequence,
>   authors of such resources should send a Vary: Origin HTTP header or
>   provide other appropriate control directives to **prevent caching** of
>   such responses, which may be inaccurate if re-used across-origins

From this statement I understand **Vary: Origin** will tell browsers prevent a cache of Preflight response (In case allow-origin: * not used)

**Access-Control-Max-Age** will tell browsers will cache preflight response for a period.

**The questions:**

1. Is it valid if both of the headers exist in a preflight response?
2. How browsers handle Preflight response if the response includes both that headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Per the spec requirements `Vary: Origin` won’t affect  behavior of the [CORS-preflight cache](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cache).

> Is it valid if both of the headers exist in a preflight response?

Yes it’s valid. But if the `Vary` header is present, it has no affect on the CORS-preflight cache.

> How browsers handle Preflight response if the response includes both that headers

For the CORS-preflight cache, browsers completely ignore the `Vary` header and only use the value of the `Access-Control-Max-Age` header.

> my understand is **Vary: Origin** will tell browsers won't cache preflight result

That’s not what the requirements in the Fetch spec say.

The [CORS-preflight cache](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cache) isn’t a general HTTP cache covered by requirements in the HTTP spec. It’s a special cache whose behavior is defined exclusively by the Fetch spec. And the Fetch spec doesn’t state any requirements—even indirectly—about the behavior of the CORS-preflight cache being affected at all by the `Vary` response header.

Instead [the Fetch spec says just this](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch):

> Let *max-age* be the result of extracting header list values given `Access-Control-Max-Age` and *response*’s header list.

That doesn’t say anything about checking the `Vary` header value before setting  *max-age*.

And because the spec doesn’t explicitly state if/how to use `Vary` when deciding whether to populate the CORS-preflight cache, then browsers *must not* use `Vary` when doing it.

If a browser did use `Vary` in its handling of the CORS-preflight cache, then that browser would be out of conformance with the spec requirements for the CORS-preflight cache.

Comment: Upvoted. The w3 site say the header Vary: Origin will prevent a cache. Can you please take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers—note that the text you cite from https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ is just an informative note—not a statement of normative requirements—but anyway it doesn’t say anything about the CORS-preflight cache & isn’t intended to be relevant to the CORS-preflight cache. Instead it says, “prevent caching of such responses”, which in the context just means the normal HTTP response. The `Vary` header is defined by the HTTP spec as something that affects normal HTTP caching, which is browsers is all implemented in whatever network stack the browser relies, not necessarily even in the core browser code

Comment: Sadly, some Web (non-browser) caches do allow users to cache responses to `OPTIONS` requests, which complicates the matter. In such cases, it makes sense to specify `Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Private-Network` in responses to `OPTIONS` requests.